# Windows XP Pro or Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, reinstall

My dual Xeon 4GB system finally unfortunately succummed to win-rot with Win XP Pro/32.  The system will not even reboot correctly in SAFE mode. So......it looks like an OS reload and application reinstall will be necessary.  This seems to happen to me between 2-3 years for some reason.

With that in mind, I am wondering if I should now go to Windows 7/64 instead of reloading XP Pro.  I figure you all out there have some fairly good information and sage advice for this.

My dual Xeon will support 64 bit mode.

I believe that applications I am using now, are Win 7 compatible but of course I'd have to now get the 64 bit versions.  Any problems running 32 bit apps on the 64 bit platform these days?

Thanks for your wisdom.

Comment: Or if there are not answers to accept, see if you can update and improve the questions.  Make sure you read and address any comments or answers left explaining why that is not acceptable.

Comment: "win-rot" does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from my own experience I would go to Windows 7.  I have had no issues with any of the applications I have been using and have had only positive experiences with Windows 7 Ultimate, Pro, and Premium.  Go for it.

Answer (score 1):

There are "some" applications that may experience trouble running in a 64 bit environment.... however I will say that I've not run into any personally.  Really I only say that there are "some" as a disclaimer more than anything.  In truth I'd recommend to go ahead and make the move to windows 7.  If you have any applications that you have serious concerns about then maybe you should look at those specifically before you make the switch.

I can tell you that at our office we've been switching everyone over to Windows 7, and at home I've switched all my machines other than a windows 2k8 server over to 7 and have had no problems.

Comment: You are more likely to have an application that has issues Windows 7, regardless of 32/64 version. You can run many problematic application in compatibility mode which fix many if not most issues.

Answer (score 1):

Our experience with Windows 7 has been positive throughout (very much in difference to Vista). You should be able to run all your 32bit applications in 32bit mode. We have upgraded several dozen of our workstations and laptops to W7 and had not had single bad word about it.